# Heroku php connection

Tags: php, database, heroku, permissions, connection

I have one php app having databse on local xampp server. Now I have hosted it to heroku how to transfer local database to heroku and while accessing index page I am getting error:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Due to "[ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)" on Heroku. Files, databases and other information which can be changed on server during runtime is not persistent.

Form the docs:

> filesystem can be used **only** as a temporary scratchpad

Consider to use 3rd party service (or one of many Heroku's addons) to store DataBase.